# Generalization of conjectures involving Beilinson regulators

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory, motives, motivic-cohomology

I had some questions about the Beilinson conjectures as mentioned in [this](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Beilinson_conjectures) page. I have to admit I do not know much about Deligne cohomology. The conjectures involve some form of comparison map between the motivic and Deligne cohomology on smooth projective varieties. This resembles very much to the Beilinson-Lichtenbaum conjecture which is a quasi-isomorphism of motivic complexes with finite coefficients and truncated Zariski sheaves that are derived pushforward of certain etale sheaves. I was wondering whether these conjectures have some sort of generalization (after replacing the Deligne cohomology by some other better behaved cohomology theory) that can be stated as a quasi-isomorphism of rational motivic sheaves with certain complexes of sheaves related to the Deligne cohomology?

The replacement for the Deligne cohomology should satisfy certain properties, like being $\mathbb{A}^1$-invariant and also certain vanishing properties which I am not sure whether Deligne cohomology satisfies or not.

1. Is Deligne cohomology $\mathbb{A}^1$-invariant?
2. Does the following vanishing hold? $H^i_{\mathcal{D}}(X,A(j))=0$ for $i\geq 2j$ and $A=\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?